# Reading file which is outside of application

Tags: java, spring, file, tomcat

I have an application deployed on tomcat which is trying to read file which is in some other directory.

**Application path (WAR file)** - /tomcat/webapp/application

**File is in directory** - /home/anotherapplication/file.txt

I've written a program (servlet) in my application to read file present at above directory structure. I've tried below option to read it but each one gave me file not found exception.

`File inputFile = new File("/home/anotherapplication/file.txt");` -- path from root directory

`File inputFile = new File("../../home/anotherapplication/file.txt");` -- relative path from application

any idea how to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: Does your application have appropriate permissions to read that file?

Comment: You have to mapping the path to something like c:\abc\def\file.txt

Comment: @pablochan - yes tomcat user have permission to read that file

Comment: Are you running Tomcat on the same machine? Perhaps you're using `chroot`?

Comment: @pablochan - running on same machine,

Comment: +1 for permission issue.. `/home/anotherapplication/file.txt` looks like private area for user `anotherapplication`

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried this?

```
File inputFile = new File("../../../home/anotherapplication/file.txt"); 
-- relative path from application
```